# How to design a thread style messaging system on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm trying to design a gmail like thread messaging system on Google App Engine by using Django-nonrel. I've watched "Building Scalable, Complex Apps on App Engine" and read the following questions on SO.

[App Engine Messaging System with Message Status - Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349529/app-engine-messaging-system-with-message-status-design-pattern/6351131#6351131)
[database design in google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662212/database-design-in-google-app-engine)

I like the idea Kevin pointed at ([App Engine Messaging System with Message Status - Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349529/app-engine-messaging-system-with-message-status-design-pattern/6351131#6351131)), so my current models are like these:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()
    thread_id = models.IntegerField()

class MessageReceivers(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message)
    users = ListField(models.CharField())
    status = models.IntegerField()  # 1 unread, 2 read ....
```

ListField on Django-nonrel is from here:
http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/03/Updates-on-djangoappengine

And here is my problem, I don't know how to achieve to display a count of messages in each thread like gmail. Let me clarify my point.
When a user, Sirius, sends a message to Harry and Ron. Models (simplified for explanation) should be like these:

```
Message
id = 1
sender = Sirius
thread_id = 1

MessageReceivers
message = 1
users = [Harry, Ron]
```

Then, Harry replies to Sirius, but for some reason he doesn't include Ron:

```
Message
id = 2
sender = Harry
thread_id = 1

MessageReceivers
message = 2
users = [Sirius]
```

And Sirius replies to Harry too, but he includes Ron again:

```
Message
id = 3
sender = Sirius
thread_id = 1

MessageReceivers
message = 3
users = [Haary, Ron]
```

And when Sirius and Harry see their inbox, there is the thread with a count of messages (3). And Ron sees his inbox there is the thread with a count of messages (2). How should I count those numbers? Should I make a new model to keep them?

Thanks in advance,
Yoo

**EDIT**
As Kevin introduced me to a Thread model and I realized that I don't need a relation index model for my requirements, so my current models look like the following.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()

class Thread(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    messages = ListField(models.CharField())    # array of message id
    lastmodified = models.DateTimeField()
    # could have a status field for read or unread, not sure for now
```

I might find difficulties in these models in further development, but I would go with them for the time being :)

Comment: Email (and by extension, gmail) doesn't do broadcast, and thus doesn't require the tricks described in that talk. Even if it did work that way, the number of recipients on an ordinary email is small enough it's hardly necessary, and for mailing lists, the listserv does the heavy lifting. Are you sure your use-case resembles gmail?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I noticed that I don't totally need a relation index for my requirements, so I decided to go with the Thread model as Kevin explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

messages = MessageReceivers.objects.filter(users='Harry')

message_threads = []
for m in messages:
  message_threads.append(m.message.thread_id)

counted_threads = defaultdict(int)

for curr in message_threads:
    counted_threads[curr] += 1
```

This will give you a dictionary of thread_id's, with their frequency of occurrence.

For example:

message_threads = ['a','b','c','a','a','b','a']

will yield

counted_threads == defaultdict(, {'a': 4, 'c': 1, 'b': 2})

Comment: p.s.  To address your suggestion of creating a new model - that could work as another solution if you are purely interested in the absolute count of messages in a thread for a given user (since it's purely additive), but if you want to be able to layer in filters on message status (ie get the count of the number of unread messages for a given user within a given thread), I recommend the approach above.

Comment: Thank you for your code Kevin. Seems your code is a good solution too, but I have one more concern. I actually want to have a paging feature. Let's say 20 threads on each page. So my real MessageReceiver model has a sent date field on it, and the query should look like `messages = MessageReceivers.objects.filter(users='Harry').order_by('-date')[:20]` (I would definitely use a cursor btw)  But that's not totally correct of 20 threads, just 20 messages and it either can't correctly count a number of messages within a given thread since there might be messages in a same thread at 20th and 21st

Comment: I know I can achieve it by making a bunch of queries but I saw a lot of times people saying "That's not scale" to such a solution and I'm unconfident. So how should I query for paging?

Comment: Seems like it would be tough to avoid at least 2 queries without creating a 'Threads' model that held a list of message keys by user and a 'last modified' field.  As I said, that works if you don't really care too much about 'read' vs. 'unread' vs. 'archived' type statuses.

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally forgot about the type statuses. But the 'Threads' model sounds really good. Okay, I'll think about it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers are going to be so low, I'd just count them on the client and forget about tallying on the server.  Download Harry's messages and count them.  Do the same for Sirius. You'll have to count them every time (less efficient) but then you don't have to store or maintain counts (more efficient) and the client's processing time is way cheaper than the server's.

This seems especially true since this number is just kind of a convenience.  If you ever want to add a feature like "sort conversations by the number of replies they have," you'll need to store the counts on the server, but otherwise you don't really care about this number.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Okay I like your idea downloading messages and counting them on the client since I don't need a sorting feature by a reply count. I'll dig into it this weekend.